# Default static HTML value in AngularJS select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a `select tag` in HTML and I am using `ng-repeat` to populate it through.

```
<td>
    <select ng-model="item.data.region" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
        <option ng-repeat="region in vm.regions track by $index" value="{{region}}">{{region}}</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

And I am making an API call for it ...

```
ds.getAllRegions(type).then(function(result){
    if(!result.length){
        vm.errorInApi = true;
    }
    vm.regions = result;
   },function(error){
    vm.errorInApi = true;
   });
```

What I want to do is...
**If the API call fails i.e. if vm.errorInApi is true, put a default static value in the dropdown like `select` and disable the select box.**

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td>
    <select ng-model="item.data.region" ng-disabled="vm.errorInApi" style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
        <option ng-show="vm.errorInApi">Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="region in vm.regions track by $index" value="{{region}}">{{region}}</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm anyway first you should add a `ng-disabled="vm.errorInApi"` in the select-tag for disabling the select box.

and i think you should change `{{region}}` in the option-tag to your default value.

Comment: that though disables but it does not add a default select option to show in case of failure.

Comment: sorry i added the second point later. just check that out: "and i think you should change {{region}} in the option-tag to your default value."